# confusion about an example of prime ideal which is not a maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, the ideal $(X)$ generated by $X$ is prime. So, it is a prime ideal. But it is not maximal because the ideal $(2)+(X)$ is a proper ideal containing $(X)$. On the other hand, we know that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is PID and in any PID all primes are maximal.  What is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong is that we know that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is *not* a PID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a PID.  Indeed, the ideal $(2)+(X)$ is not principal.  Note that $k[X]$ is a PID if $k$ is a field, but this does not hold if $k$ is a more general commutative ring.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a principal ideal domain. Suppose that $I = (2) + (X)$ is a principal ideal. So, there exists $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that every $I = \{p(X)q(X) : q(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]\}$. Since $2 = 2 \times 1 + x \times 0 \in I$, $p(X)|2$. So, $p(X)$ must be a constant polynomial. Since the only divisors of $2$ are $\pm 2$, we take $p(x) = 2$. But then $2 + X \in I$ implies that $2$ divides $2 + X$, a contradiction.

This proves that the ideal $I$ is not a principal ideal, and hence $Z[X]$ is not a PID.